# Changing DateTime format in multiple CSV files

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++, vba, csv, date-time

I've got multiple csv files with this structure:

```
text, text, 01/27/2001 01:00:00 PM
```

I need to update ALL csv files with this datetime format:

```
text, text, 27-Jan-2001 13:00:00
```

Is there a known smart/quick way of doing this? I tried importing them to Excel but that's an individual task [copy/paste one by one] so I suppose it's not the best way of doing this. Maybe some feature in Notepadd++ [couldn't find it]

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a PowerShell script to update several CSV files from a specific folder in one step.

```
ForEach ($file in Get-ChildItem "C:\myFolder" -filter "*.csv"){         
    Get-Content $file.Fullname | ForEach { 
        $arLine = $_ -split ","
        $date = [DateTime]$arLine[2]
        $arLine[2] = $date.ToString(" dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")    
        [array]$arFile += $arLine -join ","
        } 
    $arFile | Out-File $file.Fullname
    clear-variable arFile           
    }
```

#### What it does

1. Iterate through each file in a given folder and filter on CSV files only
2. Read in each CSV and loop through each line
3. Split each line into an array. The comma is our delimiter
4. Convert the the date string e.g `01/27/2001 01:00:00 PM` to a PowerShell date object.
5. Format the date object and write it back into the array. `[2]` stands for the third value/column cause we start to count at zero
6. Join back all values of current line to get a single string. Use comma as delimiter
7. Add all lines to a single array so we can write them all at once into a file
8. Proceed with next CSV file

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way would be to write a macro in VBA Excel that opens the csv files, changes the formatting and saves it as csv file again. Try the following course of action:

- [Record a macro in Excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/record-and-use-excel-macros-HA001054837.aspx) that does exactly this task for *one* csv file (start recording, open the file, do the formatting and save the file again).
- Use [this answer of SU](https://superuser.com/questions/774722/vba-code-to-update-data-in-closed-excel-files-within-a-folder-by-clicking-a-butt) to traverse through all files in a directory to do the task you just created. You'll need the [Dir function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk008ty4(v=vs.90).aspx) and a While loop.

So your code will look like this (*not tested!*):

```
Public Sub ChangeDates()
    Dim StrFile as String

    strFile = Dir("C:\Some\Location\Of\Your\Files\*.csv")
    While strFile <> ""
        # Append the stuff from the recorded macro here and adjust the filename
        # Probably something like:
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFile
        Columns("C:C").Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy HH:mm:ss"  # or something else
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        strFile = Dir
    End While
End Sub
```